# Change image size before sharing an image via email

Tags: images, gallery, share-menu

When I first used the share functionality (Share via email) from the gallery, Android asked me what should be the size of the images (fullsize / normal / small) that will be shared. I opted for regular then, and now I want to change this setting.

I cannot seem to find this setting option anywhere, anyone knows where I can change this ?

(Note: The "crop" feature in the gallery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went against the original clause in my question and used [Image Shrink Lite.](http://www.appbrain.com/app/image-shrink-lite/com.gmail.anolivetree.imageshrinklite)

Comment: If anyone else has alternative apps or ways, please mention & I'll be happy to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's an Email setting, not a gallery setting. You need to go to  Settings → Applications → Manage applications → All → Email

Then hit "Clear data" to remove your settings.

You will have to reset up your email.

Answer (score 0):

I found the option to arrange image size from within the email application itself(i use stock email app of samsung s4)

Comment: Nice for you! Mind to share where it is? ;)