# Resize photo before sending it by email?

Tags: email, photos, gallery

On iOS, when I select one or more photos from the camera storage and choose to send them by email, the OS will ask me whether to send the images in full size or make them smaller so that the email won't be so large.

On Android (stock 4.2.2 on Nexus 4) I haven't found a comparable function. When I send an email of my baby to my mom, she receives a full 8-megapixel image that's too large to view on her monitor...

**How can I have Android reduce the chosen photos before emailing them?**
I don't want to have to launch an editor app  and scale each image individually.

I only found [one 2-year-old post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/change-image-size-before-sharing-an-image-via-email) about this that doesn't mention any solution. Surely, there's a way to do this on Android, similar to how it's done on iOS?

Comment: Find similar post with a feasible solution. [http://www.droidforums.net/forum/no-way-resize-photos-when-sending-email-](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/razr-hd-razr-hd-maxx-support/232448-no-way-resize-photos-when-sending-email-observations-return-android-user.html)[image-processing](http://www.rasteredge.com/dotnet-imaging/image-processing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Image Shrink Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.anolivetree.imageshrinklite) is just right for me; there's a paid version with more options.

Answer (score 13):

There is a free (as in [freedom](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)) application [Send Reduced](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/mobi.omegacentauri.SendReduced/), available at the [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org/) repository of free software.

Install F-Droid, install Send Reduced, select your photos, press Share button, select Send Reduced and then select the sharing method. Your photos will be sent reduced in resolution and file size.

Comment: Use this one, it's perfect. Unlike many of the other apps which are severely limited, this one works exactly as you'd expect - as a transparent, easily configurable wrapper around "share to gmail".

Comment: Just had to do this quickly at work - Send Reduced also appears to be available on the Google Play store.

Comment: If you set the quality to 100%, this app actually increases the images' size.

Answer (score 9):

There is no stock option to do this.

Here's what I do, and it works pretty good, but isn't perfect.

1. Download [Reduce Photo Size from the Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shoozhoo.imageresizer).
2. When composing an email, click Add Attachment.
3. A choice of locations will pop up. Choose Reduce Photo Size.
4. Then choose either Select Image or Take a Photo.
5. If you click Select Image, then choose Gallery.
6. Once you have selected the photo you want to send, click Reduce.
7. Now a confusing window will pop up and this is where it gets a little tricky. You really have to know picture sizes as measured in pixels. Click Custom. The smallest photo size will be shown as a default (320x240 or something). I usually use 640x480 for a small 25kb pic, but you could resize up to anything you want.
8. Hit OK and then choose the three dots for the menu and choose Done.

That's it!

Comment: It is a great work flow (even works in Android 9), but a yucky GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You could try JustResizeIt! ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.perspectives.jrifree) or [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.perspectives.jri))

It's optimized to send many pictures to many emails. You can send entire albums to all your friends.

Install the free version, create a widget with many email recipients. Then open your Gallery, choose as many pictures you want, tap on Share and select JustResizeIt!. Wait the pictures to load, then just tap on the widget you predefined.

Comment: The free version is [very limited](http://www.justresizeit.com/features/) but the full version looks like a very useful tool, and very capable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a screenshot of the image, and cropping it.

It should reduce the size a bit without an app.

Comment: This is the best choice and I do most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Send it to yourself on whatsapp, it will automatically reduce the size. Then send that reduced pic in email.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativley use Google+ Auto Backup option, by default it resizes photos to 2048x2048px and reduces by size. You can then share this photo or just send it by link.

Answer (score 0):

[Quick Reduce Photo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobso.photoreducer) is a completely free app to compress any number of photos.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Blue Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.bluemail.mail). In-built feature to reduce size. Pop-up window before sending. Very efficient. Up to 10 pics in one go.

Answer (score -1):

Free [Email Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gubbins.emailphotos) android app allows photos to be easily resized (small, medium or large) and emailed.

Comment: You should have mentioned your affiliation with this product as its developer.

Answer (score -1):

What I do: put away my Android 5.5 inch screen phone for a second. Using my old iPhone 5s with a broken home button, open Google Photos where I have the pictures I need to email and send it using not gmail app, since it won't cut the size either, but mail app using gmail account.

Before releasing the wrath saying this aint the answer you were looking for or this is not an answer, allow me to explain myself, because this might be an answer for those who are like me and believe some functionalities just should be there and substituting them with apps from unknown sources just might not be a good solution.

I don't like downloading extra software containing ads (after some were firing full-screen ads right after unlocking the screen). I dont like third party apps that for no reason get access to my library. Nor do I like using them to browse through all my phone to find photos I need to email after I already nicely arranged them by albums in Google Photos and they are all in one place. Yes, Android is awesome. But iOS is good too for certain things.

I beleive that nowadays many can afford to have at least an iPhone 5 (used are very cheap) which is fast enough for functionalities that are not native to Android. Especially since iOS can easily sync with Google accounts and apps.

So I suggest to finally stop this: hey I am a Mac and I am a PC dillema and say, yes, I do use Windows when I want to play the Witcher 3, but I do use Mac for work. It's the same with Android and iOS. Yes Android is 100 times more flexible and convenient than iOS. But I do prefer some things to do on iOS devices since it's much faster and just works.